# How to perform javascript onclick operation in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular5

contend included in app.component.html file

```
<button onclick="myfunction()">Click me </button>
<script src="one.js"></script>
```

one.js file

```
function myfunction() {
  alert();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In app.component.html add click event:

```
<button (click)="myfunction()">Click me </button>
```

In app.component.ts add its corresponding function:

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
 myfunction(){
      alert();
  }
}
```

Its working for me.

Answer (score 1):

In Angular the regular `onclick` should be `(click)` or `on-click`, like this:

```
<button (click)="myfunction()">Click me </button>
```

Or this:

```
<button on-click="myfunction()">Click me </button>
```

For more info you can read about the [event binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#event-binding) in Angular.

Comment: Is it possible to inject .js file using <script src="abc.js">  in app.component.html file

Comment: @user2740299 I'm not sure, but it should work. Anyway, it's a bad practice, you better deal with external libraries via Angular CLI, just include them in `.angular-cli.json` file inside `scripts` array.